# Filtering by Column in Matlab for a list or variety of values

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've produced a code which separates data within a text file into the required format, filters the data and averages the output (in this case, the value in the fourth column)

I am trying to filter the data in column one for a list of values at the same time, with no strict pattern for the values. e.g **1001, 1007, 1048, 1192, 1200** ....

Currently my code only filters by a certain value (**1001**) is there a way of incorporating a list of values into this function?

```
 C_f = C(C(:,1) == 1001 , :);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you want,

```
val = [1000 1001];
ind = ismember(C(:,1),val);
C_f = C(ind,:)
```